# Openvpn-as : Depends: python-pyrad but it is not installable

Tags: package-management, python, openvpn, vpn, packaging

I am using Parrot OS lastest version.
I have tried and all the other variations of upgrade, such as the following,

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

I am getting the following error after running `apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as`
;

```
Hit:1 http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian buster InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                 
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                   
Hit:4 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling InRelease                                        
Hit:6 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot rolling-security InRelease         
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done                                   
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openvpn-as : Depends: python-pyrad but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

There are two up-gradable, one of which is rolling and provider doesn't advice to upgrade and it can't be upgraded whatever I tried and up-gradables are as follows,

```
mimikatz/rolling 2.2.0-git20200208-0kali1 all [upgradable from: 2.2.0-git20200104-1parrot1]
mimikatz/now 2.2.0-git20200104-1parrot1 all [installed,upgradable to: 2.2.0-git20200208-0kali1]
```

My parrot repository is as follows,

```
# parrot repository
# this file was automatically generated by parrot-mirror-selector
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

I cannot install python-pyrad, although i installed python3-pyrad. How can I fix the problem?